# Call Switch onCreate return null Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an existing project and not sure how to call the Switch button in onCreate. So the Switch button is in it's own contentView not in the main contentView the class is using. Thank you!

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_facebook.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.profile_activity.*

class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.profile_activity)

    .
    .
    .

    facebook_switch.isEnable = App.isLoginWithFacebook() <-- java.lang.IllegalStateException: facebook_switch must not be null
}
```

profile_activity.xml

```
 <LinearLayout>
        .
        .
        .
     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_preference"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        .
        .
        .
 </LinearLayout>
```

layout_preference.xml

```
 <PreferenceScreen>
        .
        .
        .
     <SwitchPreference
        app:defaultValue="false"
        app:key="Facebook_login"
        app:layout="@layout/layout_facebook"/>
        .
        .
        .
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

layout_facebook.xml

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        .
        .
        .
     <Switch
        android:id="@+id/facebook_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:theme="@style/Switch"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>
        .
        .
        .
 </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your `App` class. I guess you were calling `App` class with runtime variable asigned inside. so if your `App` class was called to another Activity before, then you call it again in your `ProfileActivity` , it would get new instance of `App` class.

I recommend you to passing App object instead to ProfileActivity than creating new instance.

Comment: The App.isLoginWithFacebook() is for SharedPreferences. It will always have a value. So I don't know why in debug console it said facebook_switch is null. Was it because the view is not created yet?

Comment: SharedPreference alwasy take context parameter and if I look on your onCreate method, you only using direct instance with no parameter constructor